# Replace em string grande ou em loop dividido

Tags: php, string, serialização, desserialização

Tenho um **array multidimensional** com algumas *rotas* e preciso fazer a conversão de alguns elementos definidos como: *(alpha), (int), (id), etc*. Como é um array, no momento eu uso um loop para fazer o replace.

Pensei em abordar outra maneira sem o loop, e trabalhar com string para fazer o replace geral. Primeiro converter o array em string usando `serialize`, depois aplicar o replace e depois retornar o array com `unserialize`.

Da forma inicial eu tinha um foreach com replaces separados, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
foreach( $array as $line )
{
    $lineA = str_replace( ',' , '&' , $lineA );
    $lineB = preg_replace( array( '(int)' , '(alpha)' ) , '([0-9]+) , ([a-zA-Z]+)' , $line[0] );
}
```

---

Com nova abordagem eu tenho serialize, unserialize e posso usar um único replace.

```
$line = serialize( $array );
$line = str_replace( array( '(int)' , '(alpha)' , ',' ) , array( '([0-9]+)' , '([a-zA-Z]+)' , '&' , $line );
$line = unserialize( $line );
```

Após o serialize, o replace vai ser em uma string um pouco grande e depois vou aplicar unserialize.

*Eu não conheço os limites de `str_replace` - é mais vantajoso um loop em strings pequenas ou um unico replace em uma string grande?*

*Não é questão sobre BENCH, apenas conhecer vantagens e desvantagens de cada caso, onde um se aplica melhor que o outro.*

Comment: Coloca o código para poder fazer os testes. Só assim pode ter uma resposta correta. Se quiser pode fazer os testes com o x-debug e o winCacheGrind.

Comment: Até pensei em fazer um bench, mas as configs do PHP e a máquina acabam influenciando.

Comment: Então todas as respostas serão com base na opinão pessoal de cada um.

Comment: De qualquer forma se fizer o teste na mesma maquina, a maquina deixa de ser uma variável.

Comment: Óbvio que não é baseado em opinião. É sobre comportamento e desempenho da função. Não sei quais limitações e vantagens de se usar replace em loop ou em uma string grande.

Comment: Para terminar. Como pode saber o comportamento e desempenho sem testar e medir?

Comment: Existe função para cada necessidade - str_replace para um caso, preg para outro... e por ai vai. Cada uma tem vantagens e desvantagens no comportamento, e eu desconheço. **Estou aguardando alguem que saiba dizer que `preg_replace` não é legal com uma string grande, ou que é mais vantagem do que um loop com 3 replaces.**

Comment: Não considero que seja baseada em opiniões, alguém já pode ter feito esse teste, ou poderá fazê-lo para responder. De qualquer forma um trecho de código será sempre bem vindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tentando responder de uma forma lógica. Eu tenho um principio que me ajuda a resolver alguns problemas. Neste caso seria assim:

- strings -> funções de strings, arrays -> funções de arrays

A função serialize é usada para tornar possível preservar tipos de dados, quando pretendemos guardar esses dados seja em algum arquivo de texto ou na base de dados. Quando necessitamos de novo desses dados vamos buscar o arquivo e chamamos a função unserialize para que esses dados voltem ao seu estado 'original'. Colocando isto de uma outra forma: se queremos guardar um array no base de dados , chamamos a função serialize que transforma o array numa string e guardamo na base de dados. Quando necessitamos de usar o array de novo, vamos buscar na base de dados e chamamos a função unserialize para termos o array no mesmo "estado" que tinhamos antes de guardar. Isto leva-nos:

1) Usar serialize, manipular a string e depois fazer unserialize pode quebrar a integridade dos dados e termos resultados inesperados quando fizermos o unserialize.

2) a função serialize ira fazer uma serie de loops para transformar a array numa string.

3) a função unserialize irá fazer uma serie de loops para transformar uma string numa array.

Conclusão:

Pelas razões acima não é boa ideia usar serialize, pois no minimo e a grosso modo irá duplicar o numero de loops.

Comment: Bacana, gostei muito. Sobre quebrar a integridade, não acho que ocorra pois são elementos exatos. A explicação que deu era exatamente o que queria saber. Acho que um loop fora é melhor que os loops do *serialize. 100% técino :)

Answer (score 1):

Achei esta pergunta muito interessante pois nesta área de programação os pormenores são muito importantes especialmente para quem lida com grandes quantidades de informação. Nesse sentido queria tentar adicionar algum valor a esta questão que é pertinente.

A questão coloca:

> Eu não conheço os limites de str_replace - é mais vantajoso um loop em
>   strings pequenas ou um unico replace em uma string grande?

Bom para isso tenho a resposta de pesquisas anteriores que é a seguinte:

A maioria das linguagens de programação limitam o número de caracteres que podem ser armazenados em uma *string*, mas o *PHP* não. Isso não significa que você pode armazenar dados ilimitados em uma *string PHP*, no entanto e enquanto não há nenhum limite no comprimento da string, um limite é imposto sobre o montante global de dados que um *script PHP* pode usar. Este limite é expresso em bytes e pode ser alterado editando o arquivo de configuração "php.ini".

Dito isto e olhando para a sua questão, observei que não considerou o `json_encode` e o `json_decode`, mas aconselho pois é uma variante a ter em conta.

Numa primeira análise parece-me ter três vias, a opção mais óbvia para a **serialização** de dados é o `serialize` e `unserialize` do PHP. Um pouco menos popular é o `json_encode` e `json_decode`. Há também uma terceira opção, usando um módulo de terceiros que se pode facilmente instalar em seu servidor. Este módulo é chamado de `igbinary`. Este último muito bom em performance mas tem alguns requisitos que nem todos os ambientes podem disponibilizar e se utilizado com `memcached` então é **bomba**.

Na **serialização** de dados, estamos sempre preocupados com o tamanho do resultado, mas também sobre o tempo que levou para que os dados sejam *serializados*.

No entanto existem documentos e testes realizados que colocam o json_encode e json_decode com ganhos de performance. Pela minha experiência diria o seguinte:

Se o seu aplicativo é mais focado em ler do que escrever, *igbinary* é o vencedor, uma vez que irá *unserialize* os seus dados mais rapidamente do que as outras funções.Contudo se você está mais focado em armazenamento de dados, json_encode é a escolha certa pois torna o seu resultado serializado mais pequeno e é mais rápido.

espero ter contribuído para o seu esclarecimento.

Comment: Interessante. Também há a possibilidade de converter em string usando `http_build_query` e retornar o array com `parse_str`. De qualquer forma - como dito pelo @Manuel Gerardo Pereira - acredito que converter um array em string e reverter o processo, pode ser mais custoso que o próprio loop. Mas é sempre bom ter outras opções, obrigado pela contribuição, não conhecia *igbinary* +1

Comment: toda a razão pois com o loop direto ao array poupa dois "layers" de conversão. Apenas coloquei a minha resposta centrada no serialize porque era uma nova forma de ver o assunto de acordo com o que perguntava e desta forma tentar enriquecer mais a resposta.